# Overlays using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, overlay

I am using ArcMap.

I have a parcels layer and I am overlaying a soils polygon layer over it.  I am trying to filter out only the parcels that contain at least 50% of their total area in the soils layer.

Is there a way to effectively do this and create a new shapefile for the filtered out parcels?

Comment: It's certainly possible, though you need to do some  math first.  What have you tried?Where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the question to contain these details.

Comment: I'm not even sure where to begin with what tools to use.  I don't have an extensive background in Arc, I'm a field forester.  So I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction.